# Color points by date in ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

Hi all: I am struggling to color points by date in ggplot2. There are two outcomes that would work for me here. 1) colour the points by the variable recent_elections and just add straight lines denoting the date of the most recent election for each point. The current code does that. 2) preferably, but harder, just add the lines, coloured differently for each election, showing a legend that printed the date of the most recent federal election.

My current data and attempt is below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

members <- structure(list(date = structure(c(6209, 6574, 7305, 14984, 15339, 
15341, 17169, 17174), class = "Date"), members = c(180835, 193225, 
200010, 86545, 95000, 128351, 41000, 124000), population = c(26449000, 
26798000, 27512000, 33476688, 33476688, 33476688, 35151728, 35151728
), votes_previous_election = c(2359915, 2685263, 2685263, 4508474, 
4508474, 4508474, 3470350, 3470350), vote_percent = c(18.8, 20.4, 
20.4, 30.6, 30.6, 30.6, 19.7, 19.7), seats_previous_election = c(32, 
43, 43, 103, 103, 103, 44, 44), recent_election = structure(c(5360, 
6899, 6899, 15096, 15096, 15096, 16727, 16727), class = "Date")), .Names = 
c("date", 
"members", "population", "votes_previous_election", "vote_percent", 
"seats_previous_election", "recent_election"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

members %>% 
  select(population, votes_previous_election, seats_previous_election, members, 
         date, recent_election) %>% 
  mutate(., members_per_capita=members/population, 
         members_votes=members/votes_previous_election, 
         members_seats=members/seats_previous_election) %>% 
  gather(Variable, Value, c(members_per_capita,members_votes, 
                            members_seats))%>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=date, y=Value, 
                group=recent_election))+
  geom_point(aes(fill=recent_election))+
  facet_wrap(~Variable, scales='free')+
  geom_vline(data=members, aes(xintercept=as.numeric(recent_election), col='red'), show.legend=F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
members %>% 
  select(population, votes_previous_election, seats_previous_election, members, 
         date, recent_election) %>% 
  mutate(., members_per_capita=members/population, 
         members_votes=members/votes_previous_election, 
         members_seats=members/seats_previous_election) %>% 
  gather(Variable, Value, c(members_per_capita,members_votes, 
                            members_seats))%>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=date, y=Value, 
                group=recent_election))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_vline(data=members, aes(xintercept=as.numeric(recent_election), col=factor(recent_election)), show.legend=T)+
  facet_wrap(~Variable, scales='free') +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Recent Election") + xlim(as.Date("1984-01-01"), NA)
```

[image]

I changed the `col="red"` in `geom_vline` to `col=factor(recent_election)` so that the vertical lines are colored by `recent_election`. The `factor()` makes sure that `recent_election` is treated as discrete instead of continuous. `scale_color_discrete` sets the legend title. Note that the election date "1984-09-04" is going out of the x range of your points, so I added a `xlim(as.Date("1984-01-01"), NA)` to also include that election date. `NA` sets the upper limit automatically.